# How to save an object with no id column?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I created a project from existing database.
The problem is with Table 'settings':
name- varchar(primary),
value- varchar.

because name is primary there is no 'setName' method on the settings entity.

when trying:
`$setting = new Settings();
$setting->setName($var);
$setting->setValue($value);
$em->persist($setting);`

I get the error "Attempted to call method "setName"

Comment: If I got it right then it won't work. Because doctrine2.1 needs a column with primary INT or BIGINT. I used to have almost the same problem and there was something with doctrine and primary key index.

Comment: According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/CPWzteZlKCI it is possible (or was possible, given the dates...), why couldn't you just add the accessors to your `Settings` class?